# Trouble with C++ Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

If you have a look at the code

```
#include <iostream>

enum Type
{
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    STRING,
};

void Print(void *pValue, Type eType)
{
    using namespace std;
    switch (eType)
    {
        case INT:
            cout << *static_cast<int*>(pValue) << endl;
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            cout << *static_cast<float*>(pValue) << endl;
            break;
        case STRING:
            cout << static_cast<char*>(pValue) << endl;
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nValue = 5;
    float fValue = 7.5;
    char *szValue = "Mollie";

    Print(&nValue, INT);
    Print(&fValue, FLOAT);
    Print(szValue, STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

The line `char *szValue = "Mollie";`is what confuses me. From what I have been learning is that a pointer is a variable that holds the address of another variable. My issues with that line obviously is that

- How come this code accepts a string into a char? We have not specified that this char is an array. Then how come?
- How come we are assigning a STRING to a pointer? I thought we could only assign other addresses to them. Where is that pointer getting its address from? Where is it storing the value?

I am still new to C++ but any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** from what I have understood from the answers below is that when we say "it assigns each letter to the memory addresses in the vicinity of szValue". The rest of the Chars in the string are stored in +1 addresses. How does C++ know how many char / addresses are in the original string? Since szvalue only contains the address of the first char. Not the others right?

Source: [LearnCPP - Void Pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/)

Comment: Protip: avoid using `void*`. In C++ use `template` instead.

Comment: `How come this code accepts a string into a char? We have not specified that this char is an array. Then how come?`  Because the rules of C++ says we can do it.

Comment: @Dai I am still learning how to program C++ hence learning about void pointers in the process but I will keep that advice in mind. Any specific reasons why templates are preffered?

Comment: @shadoweye14 `void*` is inherently unsafe, whereas using templates preserves all type information.

Comment: @shadoweye14 I really mean it.  A "string" has special rules attached to it when it comes to initialization and `char *`.  The main reason I guess is that the original designers of 'C' (which is where the rule comes from) thought of strings as "special", so needed an easy-to-use syntax.  Nothing stopped from *not* creating such a special syntax, but they did anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come we are assigning a STRING to a pointer? I thought we could only assign other addresses to them. Where is that pointer getting its address from? Where is it storing the value?

So, two things.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or the unary `&` operators (along with a couple of others), or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to`T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

A string literal is an expression of type "N+1 element array of `const char`" (plain `char` in C) where N is the number of characters in the string.

Putting that together,

```
char *szValue = "Mollie";
```

the string literal `"Mollie"` is an expression of type "7-element array of `const char`".  Since it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and since it isn't being used to initialize an array, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer of `const char`", and its value is the address of the first element.

This is an important point - arrays are not pointers.  Arrays do not store a pointer value anywhere.  Under certain circumstances the compiler will substitute a pointer expression for an array, but otherwise they're two completely different animals.

Comment: The best explanation I found so far! Thanks. A couple of things. When you say "A string literal is an expression of type "N+1 element array of `const char` ", and N is the length of the string. What is held in the '+1' part of the array? Is it the array size? or the Null Terminator/

Comment: @shadoweye14: the null terminator (I usually call it the 0 terminator to avoid confusion with the NULL pointer).

Comment: @shadoweye14: Forgot to mention, if you're writing C++, you should be using the `std::string` class instead of C-style strings.  It makes life a *lot* simpler.

Comment: Yeah that is what is confusing me. When you said pointer of `const char` and its its value is the address of the first element. 1] How is it that C++ knows how long the array is if the pointer only holds the address of the first char. 2] When we call the pointer szvalue shouldn't it return just `M` being the first element of the array instead of the whole string?

Comment: @shadoweye14: 1) It doesn't.  C-style string handling functions rely on the presence of the 0 terminator to tell them where the string ends.  2) It depends on how we use the pointer.  Yes, if we dereference `szValue` we'll get the value `'M'`; if we pass that address to a function like `printf` with the `%s` conversion specifier, the function will "walk" the length of the array until it sees the 0 terminator.

Comment: @shadoweye14: The compiler *does* keep track of array sizes during translation - given the declaration `T foo[N]`, the expression `sizeof foo` will return the number of bytes used by the array.  However, if we assign the address of `foo` to a pointer object, like `T *ptr = foo`, then `sizeof ptr` only returns the size *of the pointer variable itself*, not the size of the thing the pointer points to.

Comment: GLORIOUS! I UNDERSTAND IT!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, in C++ pointers and arrays are almost the same thing. For compiler there is no difference when you define `*szValue` or `szValue[]`.

A string literal is stored by compiler in memory and first symbol address is actually the value of the string. When you assign a string to `char *` you might get different use of the that block of memory (i.e. just pass this address into some function or iterate over symbols)

Mind examining more pages of the online tutorial you found [pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/68-pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic/). However I consider the best for learning C++ is reading Bjarne Stroustrup

**EDIT:** (credits to seand)

Pointers and arrays are almost, but not exactly the same. Take, char *x, and char y[5]. 'y' is like a pointer that points to something fixed, but 'x' may be reassigned. sizeof y yields 5. When passing x or y into functions the arrayness of 'y' disappears

Comment: When you said for a compiler there is no difference between the two definitions. Could you possibly explain in a bit more detail on how the compiler treats `*szvalue` to `szvalue[]`?

Comment: Read nikkev's answer for further explanation

Comment: Pointers are not arrays and arrays are not pointers. They aren't even close to the being the same thing.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious can you point out there differences? Can't you use `*szValue; szValue[4];`? You can't do that with void pointer, that's true

Comment: Pointers and arrays are almost, but not exactly the same.  Take, char *x, and char y[5].  'y' is like a pointer that points to something fixed, but 'x' may be reassigned.  sizeof y yields 5.  When passing x or y into functions the arrayness of 'y' disappears.

Comment: @seand That's exactly what I said in my answer: `almost`. Would you like me to add your extended explanation to the answer?

Comment: Pointers and arrays are *completely different animals*.  They are not "almost" the same.  Under most circumstances an expression of array type *will be converted* to an expression of pointer type (including for subscripting operations), but semantically they are not similar at all.  Pointer expressions may be modifiable lvalues, array expressions may not, `sizeof` behaves differently if the operand is a pointer expression vs. an array expression, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The previous two answers have covered the gist of the matter. There are strong similarities between pointers and arrays (arrays can be considered pointers to a memory location themselves). For example, when an array name is used as an argument for a function the memory address of the first element is passed to the function as opposed to the value at that location (which would be the case for an ordinary variable).

The code above assigns a string literal "Mollie" to the char pointer szValue. Therefore starting from the "M" (which is treated as a char not a string) in "Mollie" it assigns each letter to the memory addresses in the vicinity of szValue. Therefore the pointer variable szValue would point to the first element of the string, equivalent to saying szValue[0] (if szValue were declared as a char array).

Hope this helps.

Edit: 
Just to be more specific szValue points to the memory address of the first element in the string "Mollie" which is equivalent to using &szValue[0].

Comment: Awesome! that provided a bit more clarification as to how a pointer is used as an array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line `char* s = "Mollie"`, in C and C++, means this:

`s` is a pointer to a character.
It is initialized pointing to the first character in a static character array containing the characters `M`, `o`, ... `e`, and a null character `\0`.

A pointer is a pointer to a piece of memory containing a type.
That piece of memory is not necessarily a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> How come this code accepts a string into a char?

Your code isn't actually doing that, instead it's assigning the address of the first character element to the value of the pointer. *Viz*, the pointer points to the beginning of the string, incrementing the pointer by 1 will now refer to the next character in the array, and so on.

> We have not specified that this char is an array. Then how come?

You have `char*`, not `char`, that's the difference. Also, semantically `char[]` and `char*` are the same.

> Where is that pointer getting its address from?

The compiler sticks the literal string `"Mollie"` in a read-only portion of the program's memory that is loaded when the program is executed by the operating system. The value of `szValue` is equal to the address of that string literal. You'll find it's read-only and if you attempt to modify it you'll get a segfault (on *nix) or an Access Violation on Windows.

Comment: I see. So can it be safely assumed that the pointer is treated like a const pointer? To make it read only? As the value we provided it is a constant in itself. `"Mollie"`

Answer (score 0):

char *foo declares a char pointer, which in C is how arrays are represented.

So:

```
char *foo = "ABCD";
```

foo[1] == 'B'

which also means:

*(foo + 1) == 'B'

Answer (score 0):

The actual type of "Mollie" is `const char*`. You can think about it as about an array of `chars`. Thats why you can write something like this:

```
const char c = szValue[4];
```

Here, szValue is just a pointer to the first character of the string. Hence, `szValue + 1` will be a pointer to the second character and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that when you use `char *szValue = "Mollie";`, it means you assign the address of constant string "Mollie" to szValue and you can't change value through szValue, because "MOllie" is a constant value stored in constant area.